# Want to Know About Different Scenario of Memory Leaks

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am just curious about how memory leaks happens when you write a C program.

Are the following are examples of memory leaks?

1. Trying to access the part of the memory whose access is not given to your program or when you are trying to access the location of the array which is not there.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     int num[5];

     int i;

      for(i=0;i<5;i++)
           scanf("%d", (num+i));

   printf("%d\n", num[5]); //printing the data stored at loc num[5] which is not present.

      return 0;
}
```

2. Printing the value stored in an un-initialized variables.
3. Use of `void*memcpy(const*dst,void const*src,size_t n)` function memory leak occurs when `src` and `dst` pointers points to the same memory address or function is undefined when addresses overlaps.
4. Use of `free()` more than once on the same pointers which has been freed already. For Example:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int*num = NULL;

    int i;

    num = (int*) calloc(sizeof(int), 5);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        scanf("%d", (num + i));

    free(num);
    free(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Then why tag `C++`?

Comment: A memory leak just means you used `malloc` without `free`. It is not immediately a problem, but when done in a loop it will eventually eat up all available memory which will prevent the program from functioning properly.

Comment: Huh?   You leak when all user copies of a pointer to an area of allocated memory are lost, eg. by getting overwritten.

Comment: You seem to be talking about general memory-related issues, rather than just memory leaks. In fact, none of your examples are about a memory leak.

Comment: @ThingsWotsit I am confirming whether that is a e.g of memory leak or not.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Thank u very much for the answers :)

Answer (score 2):

All of aforesaid scenarios cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

- `printf("%d\n", num[5]);` is out-of-bound memory access.
- Printing the value stored in an un-initialized variables, in case of the variable has trap representation, causes UB.
- Source and destination overlap in `memcpy()`, UB.
- Multiple `free()` is also UB.

Also, memory leak is not about any *invalid access*, it is just wastage of memory leading to out of memory scenario for a system. You can read more about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: @noble_liar OK, not to misguide, once you have UB, having memory leak or not having does not matter, first priority is to fix the UB cases, then we can think of memory leaks. :)

Comment: :) can u help me understand this how can undefined behaviour of a program can cure memory leaks? Whats the difference between undefined behaviour & memory leaks.... Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @noble_liar 1) they are not directly related. 2) please read the links in the answer.

Comment: @noble_liar "Undefined behaviour" means the program can do anything it likes. It can cause a memory leak, it can cure a memory leak (unlikely), it can format the hard drive. Whatever.